# How to use loop and array with widget? Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, loops, dart, arraylist

I'm making an app that contains ViewList that have some Widget Inside it,

the Widget has functions And three Inputs (text title, text SubTitle, button with action 'OnPressed' it will change every Widget)

I need to duplicate this Widget 42 Times and every Widget has a different (title, subtitle, button)
so how I can make a loop that duplicates the Widgets and Array to enter a specific (title, subtitle, button) to each Widget?

(more Explanation) array list Contains(title, subtitle, button), every time the loop creates a new Widget in the ViewList, the Widget Get's (title, subtitle, button) from the Arraylist.

I had done that before but not in flutter not even using dart so I'm a little bit confused

this picture explains what I need
[press here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkenM.png)

Comment: Hi there. post more info as to what you have tried so far and what didn't work ? seems like you just need to traverse an array

Comment: I did everything about the Widget UI but I have two Options first copy paste 42 times
or make a loop with an array that does that and saves me some space and time.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a for loop to loop through a the lists of lists containing the information for your widgets, and add each element of the list to a text widget, you just have to make sure the elements of each list are the correct type that you have to pass to the widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List lists = [
      ['title', 'subtitle', 'button'],
      ['title', 'subtitle', 'button'],
      ['title', 'subtitle', 'button'],
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      title: MyApp._title,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(MyApp._title)),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (var i in lists)
                  Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(i[0]),
                        Text(i[1]),
                        Text(i[2]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```